# Finding Maxima/Minima of Trig Functions (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, maxima-minima

I'm having some trouble with this one, I have the following:

> [image]  the cut off part is $\frac{9}{8}$

Now, I took the derivative of it.

> $f'(x)=-4\sin(x)\cos(x)-cos(x)$

I factored it, equaled it to zero and got the following values:

> $\cos(x)=0 => \frac {\pi}{2}$ or $\frac {3\pi}{2}$
>
> $\sin(x)=\frac {-1}{4} =>$ some number (-0,25268....)

Now what I don't get is, how do I go from here to proving that $f(x)$ has a maximum of $\frac{9}{8}$.

Would appreciate some assistance, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that $$\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x =1-2\sin^2 x$$

and thus

$$f(x)=\cos (2x)-\sin x=1-2\sin^2 x-\sin x$$

then set $$t=\sin x\implies f(t)=-2t^2-t+1$$

and solve for $t\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your answer this time gimusi....

Comment: @user472288 Recall that $\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x =1-2\sin^2 x$ then $f(x)=\cos (2x)-\sin x=1-2\sin^2 x-\sin x$ and by $t=\sin x$ we reduce to study  a simple quadratic function.

Comment: Either way, we get to a point where we factor it and its going to equal the x's I mentioned in my question, how do I get from those to 9/8?

Comment: @user472288 From $\sin x=-\frac14$ we have that $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x=\frac{7}{8}$ and then $$f(x)=\frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{8}$$

Comment: Okay so I essentially input $\frac{-1}{4}$ into the original function and I get $y=\frac{9}{8}$ Did I understand this right? thanks again btw!

Comment: @user472288 We do not need to calculate x, using trig identities we can directly evaluate f(x)

Comment: Okay understood! Thanks!